# how to search a coredump files in binaries using grep -l command

Tags: shell

I want to search the core files generated in binaries using `grep -l` command 
and when using `grep -l` command I am not getting the file if the file was existed I am getting empty.

Could you please help me with examples ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you searching for exactly?

Comment: in my binaries coredump was generated i need to search core dump file generated with that binary

Comment: Well, `grep` usage is follows: `grep --options pattern list of files`.

Comment: ok  i am using like this but it is giving empty file even though file was existed 
grep -l  <binary name> <corefile path>

Comment: is there any way to search the corefiles generated for particular binary

Comment: I don't know. It depends on the structure of the dump.

Comment: ok i have to search each binary to check core dump was generated or not could you please suggest shell command to do that

Comment: Are you searching for binary name in coredumps or for coredump in binaries?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` will not look at binary files unless you ask it to explicitly with `-a` (ascii) option.